# How to make a probability table based on three columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data that looks like this,

```
df <- data.frame(col1=c(0,0,20,20),col2=c(12,20,12,20), fill=c(0,1,1,1))

  col1 col2 fill
1    0   12    0
2    0   20    1
3   20   12    1
4   20   20    1
```

**Interaction Matrix: Col1 Vs Col2, based on fill=="0"**

My motivation is to create a bipartite graph and I need the interaction of the types between col1 and col2. So, when 0 meats 12 the probability to encounter zero is 0.50. When 0 meets 20 the probability to encounter zero is 0 etc. I need to have as columns the
unique elements of col1 and as rows the unique elements of Col2

```
    0    20 
12 0.50  0

20 0     0
```

Any help is highly appreciated

**UPDATE**______

If I use the following function then I get the desired results for the fill=0. However I can not subset yet the b table to take what I want and I can not create the same result with dplyr as I want

```
df %>% 
  table() %>% 
  prop.table(.,1)

, , fill = 0

    col2
col1  12  20
  0  0.5 0.0
  20 0.0 0.0

, , fill = 1

    col2
col1  12  20
  0  0.0 0.5
  20 0.5 0.5
```

Comment: You can use `df %>% group_by(col1) %>% summarise(val = mean(fill == 0))`. Although I am not sure how 12 and 20 in the rownames is related to the output.

Comment: you are right Ronak. Thats my bad i need. I should have explained better. I want to create a bipartite graph and I need the interaction of the types. So, when 0 meats 12 the probability to encounter zero is 0.50. When 0 meets 20 the probability to encounter zero is 0

Comment: Yes but how are the rownames 12 and 20 related in the output. `col1 = 0` has only 1 value where `col2 = 12`. Does my above comment work for you?

Comment: I see your point. I ll try to clarify better. For example if I use these function 

```a=table(df)
prop.table(a, 1)```
In the table 1, where fill=0, I see what I want but I need to transpose the table. Its hard for me to generate this with dplyr

Comment: The logic behind "So, when 0 me[e]ts 12 the probability to encounter zero is 0.50. When 0 meets 20 the probability to encounter zero is 0 etc" is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be an answer to my question. Many thanks to Ronak for his comments and help

```
df %>% 
  table() %>% 
  prop.table(.,1) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% {
    with(.[.$fill=="0",],table(col2,col1))
  }
     col1
col2 0 20
  12 1  1
  20 1  1
```